# Spawner de objetos crashea cuando borro el objeto original porque pierde la referencia

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity2d, motor-de-juego

estoy haciendo unas pruebas con unity en C#. Digamos que tengo un **personaje** que es un cuadrado y que va cogiendo unas bolas que caen de arriba. He creado un spawner que va soltando las bolas y las deja en el suelo, cuando el personaje pasa por ellas activa el colider y la borra, el problema es que como se esta haciendo copias en tiemop de ejecucion de la bola original, cuando elimino esta ya pierde la referencia el clonador y por tanto crashea el juego y no spawnea mas debido a que ya no existe la bola original, no se como podria evitar esto, si dejando la bola original arriba o algo para que no caiga y no se pueda destruir.

Script.cs (las bolas, en el codigo es **hueso**)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HuesoSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject hueso;
    private float max, min;
    public float velocidadSpawn;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        hueso = GameObject.Find("Hueso");
        velocidadSpawn = 3f;


        spawnHuesos();
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    }

    void spawnHueso()
    {
        Vector2 position = new Vector2(Random.Range(-12.0f, 12.0f), 6);
        Instantiate(hueso,position,Quaternion.identity);
    }

    void spawnHuesos() {
        InvokeRepeating("spawnHueso",0.0f,velocidadSpawn);
    }
}
```

El detector de colisiones este ( con el que borro las bolas):

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Colision");
        
        //Debug.Log(col.gameObject.tag);
        string tag = col.gameObject.tag;

        if (tag == "Suelo") { 
            Debug.Log("Toco el suelo");
            enSuelo = true;
        }
        else if (tag == "Hueso")
        {
            Debug.Log("Toco hueso");
            Destroy(col.gameObject);    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No le asignes en el inspector un gameobject de tu escena a:

```
public GameObject hueso;
```

en su lugar asignale el prefab de dicho objeto.